# How to add a custom page that displays posts by views in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I'm in the process of creating a custom WordPress theme. I want to create a page that displays all the posts by views (I'm using WP-PostViews plugin) and this is what I came up with so far:

```
<?php
//get template header
get_header(); ?>

<div id="main-content" class="clearfix">
    <?php
        //get template sidebar
        get_sidebar(); ?>
    <div id='post-home' class="clearfix">
        <h2 class='block-title'><span>Most Viewed Movies:</span></h2>
        <div id="block" class="clearfix">
           <?php
           $args = array(
                        'paged' => $paged,
                        'posts_per_page' => 1,
                        'meta_key' => 'views',
                        'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
                        'order' => 'DESC'
                    );
           $query = new WP_Query($args);
           if ($query->have_posts()) { 
                while ($query->have_posts()) {
                    $query->the_post( ); ?>
                        //
                        // Post Content here
                        //
           <?php }
           } 
           ?>
        </div><!-- /End Did You Know -->
    </div><!-- /archive-entries-wrap -->

</div><!-- /main-content-->
<?php paginate_pages($query); ?>// adds the navigation pagination
<?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
<?php
//get template footer
get_footer(); ?>
```

This code works except for the navigation pagination part; the navigation bar does not appear on the page (This same code works fine if used in the index.php page).

this is the pagination code:

```
<?php

if( ! function_exists('paginate_pages')) {
    function paginate_pages($query) {
        $pages ='';
        $range = 4;
        $showitems = ($range * 2)+1; 
        global $paged;
        if(empty($paged)) $paged = 1;

        if($pages == '') {
            global $wp_query;
            $pages = $wp_query->max_num_pages;
            if(!$pages) {
            $pages = 1;
            }
        }  

        if(1 != $pages) {
            echo "<div class=\"page_paginate_pages\"><div class=\"page_paginate_pages-inner clearfix\">";
            echo "<div class=\"page-of-page\"><span class=\"inner\">".$paged." of ".$pages."</span></div>"; 
            if($paged > 2 && $paged > $range+1 && $showitems < $pages) echo "<a href='".get_pagenum_link(1)."'>&laquo;</a>";
            if($paged > 1 && $showitems < $pages) echo "<a href='".get_pagenum_link($paged - 1)."'>&lsaquo;</a>";
            for ($i=1; $i <= $pages; $i++) {
                if (1 != $pages &&( !($i >= $paged+$range+1 || $i <= $paged-$range-1) || $pages <= $showitems ))
                {
                    echo ($paged == $i)? "<span class=\"current outer\"><span class=\"inner\">".$i."</span></span>":"<a href='".get_pagenum_link($i)."' class=\"inactive\"><span class=\"inner\">".$i."</span></a>";
                }
            }
            if ($paged < $pages && $showitems < $pages) echo "<a href=\"".get_pagenum_link($paged + 1)."\">&rsaquo;</a>";
            if ($paged < $pages-1 &&  $paged+$range-1 < $pages && $showitems < $pages) echo "<a href='".get_pagenum_link($pages)."'>&raquo;</a>";
        echo "</div></div>\n";
    }
}
```

}

I don't understand why the navigation does not appear. So if you have any idea I would be thankful.

Answer (score 1):

Pretty sure that these lines:

```
        global $wp_query;
        $pages = $wp_query->max_num_pages;
```

Should instead reference your `$query` variable passed into the function:

```
        $pages = $query->max_num_pages;
```

Comment: @ToniJoe great! Please accept this answer if it was the correct solution for you